# Anti-Aliasing filter with ffmpeg or other tools to old video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have many old computer generated videos in mp4 at very low resolution 640x480.

Here an example:

[image]

I have tried to upscale it with IA but still a lot of aliasing.

I ask if there is a way to apply a anti-aliasing filter with ffmpeg or other tools to my videos.

Thanks !

Comment: Provide an example input file and show your command and the complete log.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have inserter a screenshot. I don't have any command becouse for what I known don't exist a anti-aliasing filter for ffmpeg.

Comment: Why do you want to smooth a "pixel art" game? If I were to upscale it with ffmpeg I would just use the scale filter with the neighbor scaling algorithm, or the hqx filter, and preserve the pixel art look.

Comment: I don't want to preserve "the pixel art look" I want "remove" it.I have already applied a IA frame interpolation and the now is smooth and is OK. The problem id the presence of a visible too much aliasing. With a IA upscale 2X or 4X (Topaz) the result is a bit better but not solve the problem (Topaz don't have a good Anti-aliasing filter). So for this reason I ask if is possible apply a good filter before process it with topaz.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

give a try to hqx filter or xbr filter